# How to exclude anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regex-negation

The code below will take an input and run it through a reviews list looking for the keyword and will wrap the keyword with a Mark tag which highlights it.

This almost works except that the REGEX also replaces the keyword if it is found in between anchor tags.

How can I change the regex below to ignore anchor tags?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
inputHighlight: function(){
    let currentURL = document.location.toString(),
        reviewList = $('.review-list');

    if(currentURL.indexOf('kw') !== -1){
        var reviews = reviewList.html();
        var term = utilities.queryString.getQueryValue("kw");
        term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");

        var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");

        reviews = reviews.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
        reviews = reviews.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

        reviewList.html(reviews);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick aimed to handle such "find a word but not a specific context" cases is described here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html.

In essence it is: match the undesired context or (using alternation) your pattern. Then depending on what alternative has matched, replace with the first one (i.e. the undesired context) as is or the second surrounded by the mark tags.

So replace

```
var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");
reviews = reviews.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
```

with

```
var pattern = new RegExp("<a\\b[^>]*>.*?<\/a>|("+term+")", "gi");
reviews = reviews.replace(pattern, function(match, p1) {
    return p1 ? "<mark>" + p1 + "</mark>" : match;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var term = "TEST TERM"
var reviews = document.getElementById("reviews").innerHTML;
var pattern = new RegExp("<a\\b[^>]*>.*?<\/a>|("+term+")", "gi");
reviews = reviews.replace(pattern, function(match, p1) {
    return p1 ? "<mark>" + p1 + "</mark>" : match;
});
document.getElementById("reviews").innerHTML = reviews;
```

```html
<div id="reviews">
TEST TERM
<a href="#">TEST TERM</a>
</div>
```